# Need a Math Editor to write math formulas

Tags: c++, qt, dll, open-source

Need a Math Editor to integrate to my application written on C# to be able to write math formulas. Can someone help me with this please? Some open source code will be great! Tell me steps, that integrate your suggested application to my application.

Comment: Post some code that you tried we'll see if we can help

Comment: Changing from c++ to c# (history) seems like a big and sudden change...? Anyway; what is the audience here? For example, I'd be happy with a textbox where I can type "(x + y) * z" etc - then you just need a parser and you're done.

Comment: no, that is not what i want to have, need to create a soft that will be lake MathType or Equation in MS Word for serious math formula editing

Comment: (ah, the comment related to the original version of the question)

Comment: hi dear Narek, is there any possibility to be in touch with you. Best regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend you to use a [MathML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML) based editor. The formula description is a [W3C](http://www.w3.org/Math/) standard.

A  open source MathML editor is [gNumerator](http://numerator.sourceforge.net/). It's core component and rendering engine are almost complete.

What is gNumerator?

First and foremost, gNumerator is a collection of re-usable components that make up a computer math program. Much of the value will lie in these components, and their usefullness to other developers wishing to re-use them.

To the end user, gNumerator will be a computer math system, vaguely similar to Mathematica, nucalc or Matlab. The primary difference between gNumerator, is first, it is a collection of re-usable components, and second, the use of standard languages such as MathML and JScript for user interaction. As other math programs such as Mathematica or Matlab all use proprietary languages as their form of user input, gNumerator will allow users to input standard MathML or JScript.

But, you say these languages have weak numeric abilities. Well, the 'fitness' of a language for a particular task has relatively little to do with the language itself, and more to do with the libraries availible for that language. Yes, JScript does not ship with any good numerical libraries, that is where GSL, the GNU Scientific Library comes in. One of the libraries of gNumerator will be a .net binding to GSL, this allows it to used directly from and .net language such as c#, (the language gNumerator is written in), and JScript (the gNumerator scripting language) to use the power of GSL directly. The use of GSL will give gNumerator computational capabilities on par with many commercial math packages.

The gNumerator application is will be released under the GNU General Public License, and its' library components (MathML DOM, renderer, interpreter, etc..) will be released under the LGPL, which makes them usable in a commercial application

Libraries:
There are 2 libraries that you can download the source to:
1: MathML Rendering Control
This is a Windows.Forms (winforms) control that displays MathML. All the current published screenshots are only of this control.
2: MathML DOM
This is a faithfull and almost complete implementation in c# of the w3c recomended Document Object Model for MathML This is a core, key component on which most other gNumerator libraries are built.

Here are a screenshot showing it's capabilities
[image: gNumerator Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://numerator.sourceforge.net/complex1.jpg))</sub>

On the other side (the paid), there are great products that can integrate to your project and make it available to edit formulas. One of these is [MathType](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathtype/default.htm). It's license price is reasonable, just USD$ 97.

Answer (score 3):

I would say the best solution is to let the user write the mathematical expressions in [TeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX) syntax, possibly including TeX renderer that updates as you type.

Comment: For web applications jsMath (http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/) might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use the [MEEL](http://othercontrols.com/en/products/mathexpressioneditorlight/video-primer-1/)

Comment: Hi, Andrey. I removed the spam flags from your answers as they seem to be solidly on-topic. However, you should be aware that users that come to StackOverflow and just post links to a single product page often get deleted, because the perception is that they are just here to promote their website or blog, and not contribute. Keep this in mind when posting future answers. Also, if this is your product, you need to disclose that. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq and here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15787

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you then just use Equation or MathType in our program. I'm sure they have components that you can use.
If you want open source I recommend using Math from OpenOffice.org (http://www.openoffice.org/product/math.html)

Comment: How can I integrate Math from OpenOffice to my code? I need a way how to organize the integration so that my application was able to use that capabilities.

Comment: Download it's source code and *try* to integrate to your app. I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Please look at http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/JavaBean/Configuring_the_Office_Bean and http://java.dzone.com/news/integrate-openoffice-java

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/) - it's an open source (GPL) document processor that uses LaTeX. I'm pretty sure (but not 100%) that it displays the text as you write - and the "*steps, that integrate [my] suggested application to [your] application*" could possibly be found in the source code ;-)

Another thing to check out is [LaTeXiT](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/math_science/latexit.html) (if you have acces to a Mac). It uses LaTeX to write equations. It's not open source, but maybe it'll give you some ideas.

Best of luck!

Comment: Regarding LaTeXiT, you could probably get a hold of the developer since it's a private operation.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [iMathEQ](http://www.imatheq.com), which is a WYSIWYG math equation editor. It supports exporting MathML and image.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use one of the MathML compatible editors on [this](http://www.w3.org/Math/Software/mathml_software_cat_editors.html) list? Is your C# application a web-based application or a desktop app?

Comment: it is not web based, just and exe file should be